# Bootstrap 4.0 Ordering/Moving columns for Mobile layout

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

This is how the layout look in `lg`.

On mobile devices, `sm`, I want the column order to be: 1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4

Is it possible, and/or fairly simple, using Bootstrap 4.0 or a re-write?

All my attempts using `order-sm` 1-12 has failed. I can't get column 4 to the end, to be the last column, however I go about it.

To move 4 to the end on mobile devices is the most important restructure if what I ask is impossible.

```
 _______________________
|                 |     |
|     1           |  2  |
|_________________|     |
|           |     |_____|
|     3     |  4  |     |
|           |     |  5  |
|           |     |_____|
|           |_____|     |
|___________|     |  6  |
                  |     |
                  |_____|

<div class='my-5 px-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 float-left'>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 float-left'>
        1
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right'>
        2
    </div>
    <div class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 float-left'>
        3
    </div>
    <div class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-left'>
        4
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right'>
        5
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right'>
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: It's almost what I want but the code produces a gap between column 1 and 3. Also column 6 drops below column 3. The desired place for column 6 is below 5.

```
 _______________________
|                 |     |
|     1           |  2  |
|_________________|     |
 _________________|_____|
|           |     |     |
|     3     |  4  |  5  |
|           |     |_____|
|           |_____|
|___________|
|     |
|  6  |
|     |
|_____|

<div class='my-5 px-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 d-flex flex-row flex-wrap'>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 float-left order-1 order-sm-1 order-md-1 order-lg-1'>
        1
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right order-4 order-sm-4 order-md-4 order-lg-2'>
        2
    </div>
    <div class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 float-left order-2 order-sm-2 order-md-2 order-lg-3'>
        3
    </div>
    <div class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-left order-6 order-sm-6 order-md-6 order-lg-4'>
        4
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right order-3 order-sm-3 order-md-3 order-lg-5'>
        5
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right order-5 order-sm-5 order-md-5 order-lg-6'>
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change the order of your div element to achieve what you want

Comment: Maybe usefull: https://codepen.io/preston206/pen/EwrXqm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if there was a solution to this problem using `flex` and `order` by using some properties I don't know about, so be it. But I don't have time to wait for such answer so I went for the rewrite using `jQuery` with `.appendTo()` by checking the `$(window).width()` on `$(window).resize()` instead.

Thanks all for trying. This is my solution. This works:

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        if($(window).width() < 767)
        {
            $("#mobOrder-1").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-2").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-3").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-4").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-5").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-6").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#mobOrder-1").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-4").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-2").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-6").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-3").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
            $("#mobOrder-5").appendTo("#mobAnchor");
        }
    });
</script>

<div id='mobAnchor' class='my-5 px-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 float-left'>
    <div id='mobOrder-1' class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 float-left'>
        1
    </div>
    <div id='mobOrder-4' class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right'>
        2
    </div>
    <div id='mobOrder-2' class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 float-left'>
        3
    </div>
    <div id='mobOrder-6' class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-left'>
        4
    </div>
    <div id='mobOrder-3' class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right'>
        5
    </div>
    <div id='mobOrder-5' class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right'>
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `d-flex` in `root` to use orders
you are using classes `'my-5 px-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 float-left'>`
which should be like following..

> HTML

```
<div class='my-5 px-3 d-flex flex-row flex-wrap'>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 float-left order-1 order-1 order-sm-1'>
        1
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right order-2 order-sm-4'>
        2
    </div>
    <div class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 float-left order-3 order-sm-2'>
        3
    </div>
    <div class='mt-3 mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-left order-4 order-sm-2'>
        4
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right order-5 order-sm-6'>
        5
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 float-right order-6 order-sm-5'>
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: The order I added in code may be different than you expected, just change `order-sm-*` to with order you want.

> DEMO:
>   https://codepen.io/rahul-pxl/pen/pqgmWo

Comment: It's almost what I want but the code produces a gap between column 1 and 3. Also column 6 drops below column 3. The desired place for column 6 is below 5.
I added a diagram in Original Post if you want to take a look.